# Can anyone help me how to add the annotations on the PDF

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

Can anyone help me how to add the annotations and notes on the PDF within the iphone application, so that i can view the same notes and annotation(editable form), if i open the same pdf in another PDFReader.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to forget this task for some more days that cannot be possible right now.because the ios is not providing any classes or framework for that.

Comment: I was able to do this by using the third party library called libHaru. Using this library we are recreating the PDF with the annotations

Comment: can you provide me the link..

Answer (score 0):

Check out [libHaru](http://libharu.org/wiki/Main_Page), which does what you need. It's not easy to make it "on the fly though".